# Rails 3.1.3: Evaluate ruby code before JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have controller say Home_controller providing @max = 10 @min=4. And then I later used these two values in my Home.js.erb file rests in /asset/javascript.

```
values= [<%=@max%>,<%=@min%>]
```

But it doesn't seem to be working, because when I look at the resultant javascript file from firebug, wherever I have `@max` or `@min`, they just show up as blank.

What's going on here? I am new to rails asset pipeline, so I may have some misunderstanding here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails passes the instance variables from **Controller** to **View**. So, you want to place the **home.js.erb** in the views folder and not in the assets.